# added new drives to raid 5 with wrong format then removed them and broke raid 5

Tags: ubuntu, raid

thanks in advance for any help.

In summary:  I added 3 new disks to raid 5 array.  Then, thinking they were not added, I removed them.  Now the array doesnt work.  What can I do to get back the array?

DETAILs:

I formatted 3 new hard drives with "fd linux raid autodetect" and added them to an existing raid 5 setup that was originally set up using "ext4".  When I found that the available size did not increase, I realized my inconsistent mkfs's and got hasty and removed the 3 new drives (without thinking!) and did mkfs.ext4 on them.  After reboot the array no longer would mount.  Before the installation, md was working fine.  I am kicking myself....

Since I was mounting the array to /home I have to get in using liveUSB.

I tried to force assemble and force create with the three drives figuring that since the array size never really changed, all of the data should still be on the original three disks.  Nothing seems to work.

Would changing the number of raid devices to "3" be enough to get my array back?  And if so, how would I go about doing so?

Any help would be REALLY REALLY appreciated.

Here's what I've tried and can see:

```
sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=3
mdadm: /dev/md0 is not an active md array - aborting

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/md0
mount: can't find /dev/md0 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0
mdadm: md device /dev/md0 does not appear to be active.


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=eba025dd:a180e5f2:7b9be516:8710a212 name=ubuntu:0



ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : 
md0 : inactive sda1[0](S) sdc1[3](S) sdb1[1](S)
      5860537344 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : eba025dd:a180e5f2:7b9be516:8710a212
           Name : ubuntu:0  (local to host ubuntu)
  Creation Time : Tue Dec 24 21:25:20 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 3907024896 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 19535119360 (9315.07 GiB 10001.98 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3907023872 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 44b40ccc:faf41272:21a6a41a:6f2c4798

    Update Time : Wed Dec 10 22:50:15 2014
       Checksum : 36b18224 - correct
         Events : 7953

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

    Device Role : Active device 0
    Array State : AAA... ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

The other 2 drives list basically similar info.

So then I tried a few other things:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
mdadm: /dev/sda1 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
    size=1953513472K  mtime=Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
mdadm: /dev/sda1 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid5 devices=6 ctime=Tue Dec 24 21:25:20 2013
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
    size=1953513472K  mtime=Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid5 devices=6 ctime=Tue Dec 24 21:25:20 2013
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
    size=1953513472K  mtime=Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid5 devices=6 ctime=Tue Dec 24 21:25:20 2013
Continue creating array? y
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/md0 /home
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so



ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg |tail -30
[173789.684714] md: bind<sdc1>
[173789.690771] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[173789.764322] raid6: sse2x1    3216 MB/s
[173789.832280] raid6: sse2x2    4045 MB/s
[173789.900231] raid6: sse2x4    4717 MB/s
[173789.900233] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 (4717 MB/s)
[173789.900236] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
[173789.908445] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
[173789.908450] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
[173789.908452] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
[173789.909108] md/raid:md0: device sdb1 operational as raid disk 1
[173789.909114] md/raid:md0: device sda1 operational as raid disk 0
[173789.909798] md/raid:md0: allocated 3282kB
[173789.909948] md/raid:md0: raid level 5 active with 2 out of 3 devices, algorithm 2
[173789.909952] RAID conf printout:
[173789.909954]  --- level:5 rd:3 wd:2
[173789.909956]  disk 0, o:1, dev:sda1
[173789.909959]  disk 1, o:1, dev:sdb1
[173789.909997] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 4000792444928
[173789.910032] RAID conf printout:
[173789.910038]  --- level:5 rd:3 wd:2
[173789.910042]  disk 0, o:1, dev:sda1
[173789.910045]  disk 1, o:1, dev:sdb1
[173789.910047]  disk 2, o:1, dev:sdc1
[173789.910176] md: recovery of RAID array md0
[173789.910183] md: minimum _guaranteed_  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
[173789.910187] md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for recovery.
[173789.910204] md: using 128k window, over a total of 1953511936k.
[173790.155769]  md0: unknown partition table
[173803.332895] EXT4-fs (md0): bad geometry: block count 2441889920 exceeds size of device (976755968 blocks)
```

Comment: @ Paulina have you scan and did a assemble to get back the raid set ? You have not specified the assemble command what you used. Here some of my Raid articles which will help you http://www.tecmint.com/author/babinlonston/